# Can I move entire web.xml to spring code base configuration? (WebApplicationInitializer)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, web.xml

My application will use mainly use code based configuration. From web.xml to Springs WebApplicationInitializer class I already moved: servlet, filters and mapping. However in web.xml have much more elements (such as error-page or welcome page: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html). Which of those elements I can move to code and what are their equivalents?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, yes, you should be able to get Java Config equivalents of all elements that you can set in the web.xml. In terms of converting individual elements, if you can give specifics, then we could find the JavaConfig equivalents.

Note that it's not always a 1-to-1 mapping. For example, with Spring Security, you have to define the "delegatingFilterProxy" filter in web.xml but the JavaConfig equivalent does this behind the scenes. Using Spring Security annotations triggers that behavior.

I recommend two things:

1. Read through the [Spring JavaConfig guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/) if you haven't done so
2. If you're stuck on a particular element, search for " JavaConfig". Usually, you can find some useful information quickly that way.

Answer (score 0):

For the welcome page follow these steps:

- Under your application root, create a html file called index.html
- In that declare a head section with the content:    `<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=anonymous/homepage.htm"/>`

Now when you access your application using http://myapplication.com you will be automatically redirected to http://myapplication.com/anonymous/homepage.htm. This acts as your index/welcome page

For the error page follow these steps:

In the controller:

```
try
{
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     return new ModelAndView("error");
}
```

In views.properties (or equivalent) define a error page like:

```
error.(class)=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView
error.url=/WEB-INF/jsp/errorpage.jsp
```